# How to do sequential ajax with angular (2) and rxjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, rxjs, observable

I'm both pretty new to both angular (2+) and reactive programming. So I have a feeling I'm might approach this in the wrong way, anyway here is what I'm trying to do in a sequential, synchronous order:

1. download metadata-file "a.json" from a constant path.
2. parse response into a javascript object "a". Read value "a.url".
3. download file "a.res" from "a.url"
4. parse file "a.res" and write into "a.content"
5. return object "a" containing the metadata and the content.

I know how to do this with jQuery and promises, but I'm a little clueless how to approach this with observables.

**Update**:
Here is a simple example how i would do it in jQuery:

```
function loadTwo() {
    var deff = $.Deferred();

    $.getJSON("test.json").done(a => {
        $.get(a.url).done(res => {
            a.content = res;
            deff.resolve(a);
        });
    });

    return deff;
}

loadTwo().done(a => console.log(a));
```

This yields
`Object {url: "FileInfo.xml", content: document}`

Comment: Can you show your jquery implementation? you can keep it high level and use functions just to outline the (very) high level steps. We can then help you convert that implementation to rxjs

Answer (score 0):

Something like that. Replace Rx.Observable.of({url: 'julia'}) and Rx.Observable.of('res') to http calls

```
Rx.Observable.of({url: 'julia'})
  .map(({url}) => ({url: url, a: {url: url}}))
    .switchMap(({url, a}) =>
      Rx.Observable.of('res')
        .map(res => Object.assign({}, a, {res: res})))
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```